# save mesh with RGB in vtk

Tags: c++, vtk

I have a mesh (with color) loaded and want to write it to a .ply file and store the rgb information as well. I currently have the code below, which uses the `vtkPLYWriter` class, but this just saves the vertices and not the RGB info. Is there a built in way to do this?

**Code**

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransformPolyDataFilter> rotate_and_save_mesh(vtkSmartPointer<vtkPLYReader> mesh_reader, double rotation_angle, double x, double y, double z, 
        std::string& out_name, bool should_write = true){
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform> transform = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransform>::New();
    transform->RotateWXYZ(rotation_angle, x, y, z);
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransformPolyDataFilter> transformFilter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTransformPolyDataFilter>::New();

    transformFilter->SetTransform(transform);
    transformFilter->SetInputConnection(mesh_reader->GetOutputPort());
    transformFilter->Update();

    if(should_write){
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPLYWriter> writer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPLYWriter>::New();
        writer->SetInputConnection(transformFilter->GetOutputPort());
        writer->SetFileName(out_name.c_str());

        writer->Write();
    }
    return transformFilter;
}
```

Comment: check this out.
[link](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/IO/WritePLY)

Answer (score 1):

This is very awkward. Unlike vtkPolyDataXMLWriter and most other VTK writers, you must specify

```
plyWriter->SetArrayName("Colors");
```

where your color array was created/named like this:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnsignedCharArray> colors =
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnsignedCharArray>::New();
colors->SetNumberOfComponents(3);
colors->SetName("Colors");
```